# Views resetting to original interface builder height and constraints after scrolling in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have two views, a UIWebView and a UITableView, that I am programmatically expanding their heights. Both of these views are located inside a UIScrollView. Both the WebView and TableView have had their scrolling disabled, and the ScrollView and its parent views have Autoresize Subviews turned off. What I'm trying to do is expand both item's heights to the appropriate sizes, then expand the ScrollView's content size to the sum of both items. Right now that works. However, as soon as I scroll the TableView and WebView reset to their original heights, but the ScrollView maintains its new content size.

I am changing the heights in webViewDidFinishLoad with the following code.

```
// Set the webview height //
webView.frame = CGRectMake(
                           webView.frame.origin.x
                           , webView.frame.origin.y
                           , webView.frame.size.width
                           , webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);

[webView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[webView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                        constraintWithItem:webView
                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                        toItem:nil
                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                        multiplier:1.0
                        constant:webView.scrollView.contentSize.height]];

webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;

// Set the table height and location //
self.myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.myTableView.frame.origin.x
                                      , webView.frame.origin.y + webView.scrollView.contentSize.height + 8
                                      , webView.frame.size.width
                                      , [tableRows count] * 40);

[self.myTableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.myTableView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:self.myTableView
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:nil
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                   multiplier:1
                                   constant:[tableRows count] * 40]];

// Update the scrollview //
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, webView.frame.size.height + self.myTableView.frame.size.height);
[super updateViewConstraints];
[self.myScrollView setContentSize:newSize];
```

I'm guessing I'm missing a step somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was wrong. `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` need to be set to `YES` when inside a ScrollView. This is `NO` by default so removing that line did not work, it must be explicitly set to `YES`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you are trying to use both static frames and constraints at the same time. This would not work and is the reason why the frames of the tableView and the webView go back to their initial values.

Making this work with constraints will be a little bit more complicated, but if you just use the static frames and remove the constraints you're adding by code, all should work fine.

Good luck!